# How to scroll only top layer to cover over bottom layer in browser?

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

In this example, they somehow are able to scroll the top layer in the browser to cover over the bottom layer div. How can that be done with jquery/CSS?

[www.sevenly.org](http://www.sevenly.org/)

Comment: I also like to find out how they animate the scrolling in that way. thanks a lot.

Comment: Use Absolutely Positioned Divs (AP Divs) which include the z axix

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea how you can achieve this. You can improve this to your needs. The background layer is fixed as well as the `<nav>`-element. All elements have different values for `z-index` to make the content scroll between the background and navigation.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/RjGsM/

**HTML**

```
<div class="background"></div>
<nav></nav>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: red;
}

div.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 300px;
    background: blue;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: What about more than 2 sections? (more `.content `)

Answer (score 0):

Add {position: fixed} to the "layer" (div) you don't want to be scrolled. Make sure it's z-index is lower than the divs that do scroll.

But be warned, the mobile compatibility for this isn't great :)

Answer (score 0):

This effect is achieved by adding some padding to your body element ( sevenly.org uses 600px - about right ), and then absolutely positioning an element in the background.